# How do I center a figure vertically in moderncv?

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, captions, minipage, moderncv

I would like to center a figure vertically in moderncv. I cannto use the figure environment and not the caption package in moderncv, hence I use minipage and a manual caption. Please consider the following example, to understand what I mean.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle Moduli spaces of stable maps and curves' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{lipsum} % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
%\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{Christoph} % Your first name
\familyname{Mark} % Your last name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle % Print the CV title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Works}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \centering\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.jpg}\\
  Figur 1: heading of figure.
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

The graphic is spread to the textwidth which is fine. But I would like to put in several graphics (in total 15), one on one page each, and centered vertically on the page. I don't want that the ratio between height and width is changed, however.

Comment: Onw way to center something vertially is to put `\vspace*{\fill}` above and below.  Another is to use something like `\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth} ... \end{minipage}`.  The secnd [c] centers the contents inside the minipage.

Comment: Thank you! It might be obvious for you, but a great help for me @JohnKormylo